# Alternate way to find memory usage of system and program

Tags: c#, .net, memory, mono, memory-management

I want an aleternative to find total memory usage and memory used by individual process without using System.Diagnostic in C# program, as I am developing an application on Mono implementation for one device and it doesnt have any System.diagnostic implementation yet.

thanks,
Milan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find `GC.GetTotalMemory(false)` to be useful. You can read about it here :

- [dotnetmonster](http://www.dotnetmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/dotnet-framework/5562/What-does-GC-GetTotalMemory-really-tell-us)
- [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582967/what-is-the-difference-between-gc-gettotalmemoryfalse-and-gc-gettotalmemorytru)
- [MS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.gettotalmemory.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Did you try using GC itself?

```
        long trackStart = System.GC.GetTotalMemory(true);

        //your code goes here
        byte[] testData = new byte[50000];

        long trackEnd = System.GC.GetTotalMemory(true);

        long diff = trackEnd - trackStart; //You get bytes used.. may not be exact size
```